# ant warning : could not load antlib.xml

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I have the antcontrib.jar in my lib folder of Ant. I set my ant home as "C/Prog Files/apache-ant".

But still when I run my build.xml, i get the warning "could not load antlib.xml and antcontrib.prop".

Because of this, I am not able to do any "regex" operations.

I properly loaded the antcontrib.jar in the lib folder of the ant.

Where I am wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Provide `resource` and `classpath` in your `taskdef` correctly as follows

```
<typedef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" classpath="<path to ant-contrib.jar>"/>
```

Comment: I have added my ant-contrib.jar in lib folder of ant. So I believe no need to add the classpath. If we add the ant-contrib.jar in any other location then we may need to add the classpath...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of an Ant script that uses Ant-Contrib's `<propertyregex>` task:

### build.xml

```
<project name="ant-propregex-simple" default="run">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />
    <target name="run">
        <property name="line.to.test" value="First Second" />
        <property name="the.regex" value="^([^ ]*) ([^ ]*)$" />
        <propertyregex 
            input="${line.to.test}" 
            regexp="${the.regex}" 
            select="\2" 
            property="the.match" 
        />
        <echo>${the.match}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

The key is the `<taskdef ...>` line.

### Output

```
run:
     [echo] Second

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```